# Jenkins, ADVANCED REST API

Tags: rest, jenkins

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CcsbL.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y52pm.png)
Alright I am stuck now....Please help. Here is a picture of POST request in a REST API and a picture of the Jenkins build parameter. The request is working in the external REST client but when I import the payload to the build parameter in Jenkins I get a bad syntax error. Everything has to be done in JSON – user3516719 7 mins ago

Comment: How does your job post this payload?
Can you provide more information about this job? Are you using any plugins? Personally I find it easier to use a powershell/shell script to automate my RESTful requests to other services, however, I believe there are plugins that accomplish this.

Comment: We are using the HTTP plug in for Jenkins. Everything needs to be in SON not sure if we can use powershell. How would you use powershell if you could?

Comment: Sending a JSON shouldn't be a problem.
I will post a simple script as an answer so it will be more readable

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned above in the comment, here is a very simple powershell script that will send a JSON payload, you will need to call it with the two parameters(e.g. script.ps1 -JsonFile "C:\1.json" -IpAddress "1.1.1.1"):
(Please consider this may require some tweaking as I have not tested the below code, you may want to modify Method POST/PUT or the resource structure).

that will send a JSON payload:

```
   Param(
  [String]$JsonFile,
  [String]$IpAddress
  )

  Function RESTRequest ($IpAddress, $JsonContent)
  {
        $RequestHeader = @{};
        $RequestHeader.Add("Accept", "application/json");
        $resource = "http://$IpAddress/"
        # Add more headers here if required
        $response = Invoke-RestMethod -Method POST -Uri $resource -Headers $RequestHeader -ContentType "application/json" -Body $JsonContent -ErrorAction Stop
        Write-Host $response
  }
$JsonContent = Get-Content -Path $JsonFile
RESTRequest -IpAddress $IpAddress -JsonContent $JsonContent
```

Comment: Thank you.Where would this be implemented in the raw portion of the payload?

Comment: Not sure I understand the question, but you probably want a "Freestyle" jenkins job which will run the above script. Just place the JSON you want to send in the workspace and point to it with the script:
e.g. Powershell step - "Invoke-Expression path\to\script.ps1 -JsonFile $env:WORKSPACE\payload.json -IpAddress "1.1.1.1"